# Convert array to array-like object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array, say `[{ id: 'first' }, { id: 'second' }]`

Are there any native methods I'm missing that will convert the array into an array-like object? I've seen plenty of answers asking about the other direction, and recommending `Array.prototype.slice.call` (or the newer `Array.from`), but I can't find anyone asking about this. For the above example, I'd want to get the following output:

```
{
  0: { id: 'first' }
  1: { id: 'second' }
}
```

Comment: Use array.reduce and code it yourself?

Comment: `New Set(array)` <- that would create an array-like object, a Set

Comment: @user2415266 maybe you could help him out since it seems he's new to programming

Comment: @Wade maybe he could search before asking a duplicate question

Comment: @user2415266 maybe you should read the [ideologies stack overflow is trying to represent](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) before being so rude to new contributors and programmers

Answer (score 4):

Reducing it

```js
var array = [{ id: 'first' }, { id: 'second' }];
var obj   = array.reduce( (a,b,i) =>  {return a[i]=b,a},{})

console.log(obj)
```

Check out the documentation on `Array.reduce` on [MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate through the `array` and add the values to the respective index

```js
var arr = [{ id: 'first' }, { id: 'second' }];
var set = {};
arr.forEach(function(value, index){
    set[index] = value; 
})

console.log(set)
```

Comment: Nice solution! You should check out @adeneo 's answer using `Array.reduce`, it does the same thing but using javascript's built in methods

Answer (score 0):

Not a native method, but the following helper function should do the trick:

```
var arr = [{ id: 'first' }, { id: 'second' }];

function toArrayLike(arrayToConvert) {
    var retVal = {};
    Object.keys(arrayToConvert).forEach(function(key) {
        retVal[key] = arrayToConvert[key];
    });
    return retVal
}

var arrayLike = toArrayLike(arr);
console.log(arrayLike);
```